# DatagramSocket in processing

Tags: java, udp, processing

https://pp.userapi.com/c639520/v639520057/34532/qDwH5lGq1FQ.jpg

Problem with DatagramSocket and SocketException.

DatagramSocket is not exist
SocketException is not exist

Coded on processing 3.3.3. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Googling "DataGramSocket Java" reveals that it's just a standard Java library in [the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html). So you don't have to download anything. It's not in a library.

You just have to import the class, or use the fully qualified name. Check out the link to the API to figure out which package it's in.

Comment: try to download JDK. may be it help me

Comment: @СеваРачис Processing uses Java behind the scenes. You shouldn't have to download anything else.

Comment: but everything "is not exist"

Comment: @СеваРачис Please post the full text of any error messages you're seeing along with a [mcve].

Comment: make a screne and write a problem

Comment: problem solved. import java.net.*;